# Reading XLSX data from subfolders on desktop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook, readfile

I am trying to read an excel file into a dataframe using pandas and jupyter notebook from subfolder on my desktop. The file is on my desktop in a folder called 'Data', subfolder 'KN-Data', subfolder 'New-Files', file name "Customers.xlsx".

Here is the code I am trying:

```
df_customers = pd.read_excel (r"C:/Users/Zach/Desktop/Data/KN-Data/New-Files/Customers.xlsx")
```

Error is

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Zach/Desktop/Data/KN-Data/New-Files/Customers.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double backslash instead of single forward slash. I always use double backslash and it works for me.

This is how ur code should look like:

```
df_customers = pd.read_excel (r"C:\\Users\\Zach\\Desktop\\Data\\KN-Data\\New-Files\\Customers.xlsx")
```

Comment: for every single slash?

Comment: @ZachCornelison S

Comment: Did u use backslash?

Comment: yes ive tried backslashes and forward slashes, single and double

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222257/discussion-between-zach-cornelison-and-sushil).